# error 127 while installing yeoman

Tags: yeoman

When I execute : `sudo npm install -g yo`

I am getting this :

> npm WARN engine yo@1.7.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2:
>   this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date
>   with respect to npm npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.1: wanted:
>   {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.1:
>   wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine hawk@3.1.3: wanted:
>   {"node":">=0.10.32"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm
>   WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5:
>   wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3:
>   wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current:
>   {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.4.21"}) /usr/local/bin/yo ->
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
>
> > yo@1.7.0 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
> >     yodoctor
>
> /usr/bin/env: node: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type npm WARN This
>   failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" npm WARN For
>   further explanations, please read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian 
>   npm ERR! yo@1.7.0 postinstall: `yodoctor` npm ERR! Exit status 127 npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.7.0 postinstall script. npm ERR!
>   This is most likely a problem with the yo package, npm ERR! not with
>   npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     yodoctor npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm ERR!
>   npm owner ls yo npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-16-generic npm ERR! command
>   "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" npm ERR! cwd
>   /usr/share/applications npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25 npm ERR! npm -v
>   1.4.21 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!  npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /usr/share/applications/npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0

Anybody knows how to solve this issue?
Thank you.
I am on Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. I tried followings.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs ^node-* nodejs-*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
npm -v
```

This was solved my issue, then installed yeoman,

```
npm install -g yo
```

Comment: your answer resolved the same problem on my ubuntu. The fact is I forgot to add the _link_ for **nodejs** and **npm**, i-e `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node` and `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm`. So when I would like to install `yeoman generators`, `grunt` and other package, I have the same error mentionned as below. Check this [link](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nodejs) in order to have a properly intallation of **node js** and **npm**. Thank you for the answer by the way.